# How to share keyboard and mouse in Sonoma?

Tags: sonoma

I have a MacBook and a Mac Mini. I used to share a mouse and keyboard, but after updating to Sonoma, if I try to do the same, it mirrors the screen, and I don't have two computers; I only have one.

The steps I do to reproduce this are

1. Go to System Settings
2. On the left side, I click on **Displays**
3. Click on the **+** and select **Mac Mini Studio**

Has this behavior for sharing the mouse and keyboard been removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you select your Mac Mini Studio from the list, you should see it twice, once for "Mirror or extend to" and once for "**Link keyboard and mouse to**". Make sure you select the second option. Here's an example of what you should see (it should be the same options for a Mac Mini):

[image: Screenshot on macOS Sonoma of System Settings > Displays]

If you don't see the option to "Link keyboard and mouse to" your other Mac, you'll have to go to *System Settings > Displays > Advanced* and enable "**Allow your pointer and keyboard to move between any nearby Мас or iPad**". I've tried to connect to my iPad with this disabled and I was only able to "Mirror or extend to" it.

[image: Screenshot of the Advanced options in System Settings > Displays on macOS Sonoma]

<sup>Click image to open full size</sup>

---

<sub>To be sure if it's working, you can check the current state of the display options in the menu bar (just add the module in *System Settings > Control Centre*). You should see this icon if it's working: [image]</sub>

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Thinkr I will try to find out why I don't see the "Link keyboard and mouse to" option

Comment: Are you signed in with the same Apple ID on both devices?

Comment: I've just double-checked and am logged in with the same Apple ID; I also have the "mirror or extend to" option, but I don't have the "Link keyboard and mouse to."

Comment: @agusgambina I have edited the answer with the solution to the problem. I've tried with different configurations and eventually managed to replicate the problem and to find a fix. :)

Comment: Thank you @Thinkr. I already had that configuration, but just in case it helps someone else, I restarted the computer, and it seems it worked.

Comment: @agusgambina Oh nice! It might just have been a bug then :)